# Bulk Insert with child entities using EF6 extensions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-extensions

I'm getting an error everytime I try to bulk insert using **EF6 Extensions library**

> When using `IncludeGraph`, some options must be set in the `IncludeGraphBuilder` (See: 
>     https://entityframework-extensions.net/include-graph). The following options must be specified in `IncludeGraphBuilder: ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression, LambdaPrimaryKeyExpression`

The schema is as follows 
Customer(PK,____,AddressId)
CustomerAddress(PK,____,AddressLookupId)
CustomerPhone(PK,___,CustomerId)
AddressCities(PK,CityName)
AddressLookup(PK,Zip,CityId, StateId)

I have the following as a lookup table
AddressStates(PK,_____)

options for filling the data as follows

```
options.InsertIfNotExists = true;
options.IncludeGraph = true;
options.IncludeGraphOperationBuilder = operation =>
                {
                    switch (operation)
                    {
                      case BulkOperation<Customer> customer:
                            customer.InsertIfNotExists = true;
                            customer.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => new { 
                            x.FirstName, x.MiddleName, x.LastName};
                            customer.AutoMapOutputDirection = true;
                            //customer.LambdaPrimaryKeyExpression = 
                            customer.AutoMapIdentityExpression;
                            break;
                        case BulkOperation<CustomerAddress> customerAddress:
                            customerAddress.InsertIfNotExists = true;
                            customerAddress.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => 
                            new { x.Address };
                            customerAddress.AutoMapOutputDirection = true;
                            //customer.LambdaPrimaryKeyExpression = 
                            customer.AutoMapIdentityExpression;
                            break;
                        case BulkOperation<CustomerPhone> customerPhone:
                            customerPhone.InsertIfNotExists = true;
                            customerPhone.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => 
                            x.PhoneNumber;
                            //customerPhone.LambdaPrimaryKeyExpression = 
                            customerPhone.AutoMapIdentityExpression;
                            customerPhone.AutoMapOutputDirection = true;
                            break;
                        case BulkOperation<AddressCity> addressCity:
                            addressCity.InsertIfNotExists = true;
                            addressCity.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => 
                            x.City;
                            //addressCity.LambdaPrimaryKeyExpression = 
                            addressCity.AutoMapIdentityExpression;
                            addressCity.AutoMapOutputDirection = true;
                            break;
                        case BulkOperation<AddressLookup> addressLookup:
                            addressLookup.InsertIfNotExists = true;
                            addressLookup.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => 
                          new { x.Zip, x.CityId, x.StateId };
                            //addressLookup.LambdaPrimaryKeyExpression = 
                            addressLookup.AutoMapIdentityExpression;
                            addressLookup.AutoMapOutputDirection = true;
                            break;
```

I also tried setting the ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression to map the columns that should stay unique and no luck.

Update 1 : Added the Customer options inside the graph builder, error has changed to violation of FK Constraint on City, even though it's set to only allow cities that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting any settings for Customer. That likely is the issue

Comment: I've updated the code, and thanks for your comment ... that sure started putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by adding 
     `<EntityType>.AllowDuplicateKeys = false;` 
and I had a null key value in some records so I had to filter them out